# Does transferring funds from a contract to an unclaimed address create a new account?

Tags: transactions, contract-invocation, evm

I sent funds to some addresses via a proxy contract and later couldn't find those addresses on a block explorer. Sending directly from metamask to one of those addresses did reveal the address on the block explorer, also containing the funds sent to it previously by the contract. Note that I'm doing this on a non-Ethereum testnet, but I suspect this has something to do with the evm, which is used by the network.

Comment: What block explorer? This is probably a bug in the block explorer, where it fails to index accounts that have never been involved in an "external" transaction.

Comment: This is probably right, it doesn't seem like internal transactions are logged anywhere.